# Problem with DB2 Fixpack 11.1 Fp5 installation

Tags: linux, db2, db2-luw

I tried to install the DB2 V11.1 FP5 on a SLES-12-SP4 machine. So far I

- downloaded the universal package
- extracted the universal package
- called the command `"./installFixPack -b /opt/ibm/db2/V11.1/ -p /opt/ibm/db2/fp5/"` as root user

But the installFixPack stopps working sometimes at step 44 or 47 or also step 50 of 73 without any clear error message. In the log file I find a message like

> "ERROR: The install path "/opt/ibm/db2/fp5" is invalid. Specify a
> valid install path.
>
> ERROR: DBI20105E  An error occurred while installing the following
> file set: "DB2_PRODUCT_MESSAGES_FR_11.1.4.5_linuxamd64_x86_64".
> Because these files were not successfully installed, functionality
> that depends on these files might not work as expected.

Rolling back what has been installed"

Any hint what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much for reading so far
best regards
Thomas Graf

Comment: You can use an additional option to trace what is happening , `-t /tmp/fixpack.trace` . This should give details about what's wrong with `/opt/ibm/db2/fp5` if it is not obvious already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./installFixPack -b   is to patch an aleady installed DB2 HOME cf: pass from FP4 To FP5.

if you want to install the FP5 into a new path use db2setup (or ./db2setup -r  for silent install)

you should add -l /var/tmp/installlog.log -t /var/tmp/installtrace.log to the installFixPack to see exactly what is the error.

Comment: My fault: I tried updating an existing DB2. Now I found an additional problem during the install: the update for TSAMP is failing with this error: 
Installation failed with return-code: 2 : /srv/db2/data1/universal/db2/lin[...]64/src.msg.en_US-3.2.4.0-19150.x86_64.rpm /srv/db2/data1/universal/db2/lin[...]64/tsamp/Linux/x86_64/src.msg.en_US.UTF-8-3.2.4.0-19150.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
 src >= 3.2.4.0 is needed by src.msg.en_US-3.2.4.0-19150.x86_64
 src >= 3.2.4.0 is needed by src.msg.en_US.UTF-8-3.2.4.0-19150.x86_64"
Still I'm confused what I can do to solve the problem

Comment: AI... never install TSAMP if you don't need it. if you don't need it, uninstall the TSAMP rpm before the upgrade.

Comment: Hi, I uninstalled TSAMP. After that the installation of FP5 was succesfull, also the instance update worked for all instances in the DB2 server. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Even if you started the install with root, the app can use another user to install some files/libraries.

Do you have the same message after manually creating this folder ?

Comment: Hello, I receive the error message when the folder is created manually and if the folder is entered in an interactive call of the installFixpack